# AngularJS 404 error

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 error in Chrome's console for one of my routes.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {templateUrl: "home/autocomplete.html", controller: "TypeaheadCtrl"})
  .when("/search", {templateUrl: "search/search.html", controller: "TypeaheadCtrl"})
  ...
}
```

The first route (`/`) works fine. Why does the second route (`/search`) throw a 404 error?

This is the error Chrome gives me:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

The url is: http://localhost:8000/app/. Yet, both my templates are displaying. I don't understand why I would get a 404 error for that url and yet both my templates display?

Comment: Which document throws the error? Check the "Network" tab for 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

This was actually very simple and solved it as I was putting the question together.

The error was caused by this bit of code

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
  <img alt="Brand" src="...">
</a>
```

It was the ellipsis in the `src` attribute, once removed, everything works fine. Posted just in case someone else makes the same silly mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Both the routes are pointing to the same controller.Is it desired behavior. else please change the controller of the search route to different controller to make it work.